No redirect after login with cusom next.js login UI in Firefox
I have a Duende Identity Server with a custom next.js login UI, that serves as a token authority for an API (possibly multiple APIs in the future). The API is accessed through a single page application written in next.js.
In Chrome based browsers everything works as expected, SPA redirects to login UI, login UI sends a login request to an API-endpoint in the Identity Server, on success calls the connect/authorize endpoint, then redirect to SPA with an authenticated user.
However, when using Firefox with the default privacy settings, I end up at the login UI, not the SPA.
If I change the privacey settings to "Custom" with only blocking cross-site tracking cookies everything also works as intended. Also, if I add the login ui to the list of exceptions in privacy settings everything works as well.
Signing in with external providers like Google or Apple is not effected and works regardless of browser privacy settings.
Unfortunately, I don't get anything from Firefox's console.
Everything is served over HTTPS, SameSite is set to None and Secure is also set in the Cookies.
The SPA, the API, Identity Server and the custom Login UI are all hosted on Azure, but on different Domains:

SPA: Hosted as Static Web App at spa.azurestaticapps.net
Custom Login UI: Hosted as Static Web App at loginui.azurestaticapps.net
Identity Server: Hosted as Web App at identityserver.azurewebsites.net
API: Hosted as Web App at api.azurewebsites.net

I have no clue why that is happening but I assume that Firefox isolates or blocks the third party cookies from the Identity Server so that they are not available in the SPA.
I would be thankful for any advice on how to get Identity Server to work with a custom login UI in Firefox.
Is there anything I can do in the Identity Server's configuration or does this have to be somehow fixed in the frontend?

"Also, if I add the login ui to the list of exceptions in privacy settings everything works as well." That sounds like the correct solution. It's much better than turning almost everything off for everything.

Thank you for your reply, prompting the user to add the page to the privacy exceptions would be a last resort. Fortunately, moving the ui and backend to the same domain solved the problem

As long as the user has one server he trusts, it's way better to add a single exception than to disable protection for the entire Internet. Theoretically the server is trusted because it's not behaving badly. I see below that they could move the server domains, because they controlled the server domains. That's not always possible.

Here's how we fixed this:
We moved the login UI and the Identity Server to the same domain.
The Identity Server is now running on backend.example.com and the UI is running on portal.example.com
